# access the variable in activity in another class

Tags: android

In my application I need a variable from one activity to another activity without using any intent. So I have declared that variable as static and used as `FirstActivity.a` but this is returning so null, Hence I have created a class that extends application and declared that variable there still I am getting null. no clue how to achieve this.

Googled a lot but everyone are suggesting either to use static or extend Application class, unfortunately both are not working for me.

Application class:

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application{

    private String StockName;

    public String getStockName() {
        return StockName;
    }

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        StockName = stockName;
    }



}
```

Setting the variable in one activity as:

```
public class Detail extends Activity{

ApplicationClass ac;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stockdetail);
        ac=new ApplicationClass();

        ac.setStockName(getIntent().getExtras().getString("StockName"));
}
```

Retriving the variable in another class as:

```
public class Table {

    Context c1;

    Cursor c;
    ApplicationClass ac=new ApplicationClass();

public String selectdate="Select " + column1 + " as _id, " + column2 + " From " + tablename + " Where " + column3 + " = " 
                                + ac.getStockName();
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this.

### Edit

```
public class Detail extends Activity{

public static sname;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stockdetail);

        sname=getIntent().getExtras().getString("StockName");
}

public class Table {

        Context c1;

        Cursor c;

    public String selectdate="Select " + column1 + " as _id, " + column2 + " From " + tablename + " Where " + column3 + " = " 
                                    + Detail.sname;
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new object (`ApplicationClass ac=new ApplicationClass();`) again in `Table` class?

Comment: Try to use spring for android :)

Comment: @JoelFernandes Is it not required? Sorry to ask but I am newbie to both and android and java.... Is it wrong way.. in that case how to use the variable in application class?

Comment: @Rafik991 Thanks for your reply.. how to use what is the process? I am newbie to android. I have done 80% of my application now if I use spring do I need to change the whole application?

Comment: @Siva Check my answer below on how you can access static objects/variables

Comment: Read my answer ;) there is no need of spring if you simply don't want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Edited]**

Since you're saying that there is a value returned from this line `getIntent().getExtras().getString("StockName")`, then try this code:

```
public class Detail extends Activity{

public static String stringValue; //make it public and static

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stockdetail);

        stringValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("StockName");
}
```

Now access the static object in Table class:

```
   public class Table {
        Context c1;
        Cursor c;

      public String selectdate="Select " + column1 + " as _id, " + column2 + " From " + tablename + " Where " + column3 + " = " + Detail.stringValue;

}
```

This should work properly. Make sure you're accessing the `stringValue` variable after the `Detail` activity is created.

**[Original Answer]**

Try this:

```
public class Detail extends Activity{

public static ApplicationClass ac; //make it public and static

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stockdetail);
        ac=new ApplicationClass();

        ac.setStockName(getIntent().getExtras().getString("StockName"));
}
```

Now access the static object in `Table` class:

```
public class Table {

    Context c1;

    Cursor c;

public String selectdate="Select " + column1 + " as _id, " + column2 + " From " + tablename + " Where " + column3 + " = " 
                                + Detail.ac.getStockName();
}
```

P.S. To access the static object/variable, follow this syntax:

```
Class_Name.Object_Name.Method_Name();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when I tried this way I am getting null pointer exception where I used `Detail.ac.getStockName()`

Comment: Is the `Detail` activity called before the `Table` class? Also, do check if you're getting any value in this `getIntent().getExtras().getString("StockName")`

Comment: Actually class where I want to use the application variable is not activity... I will use that in a string and will pass that string from table class to Detail(Activity) class

Comment: Ok my bad. Didn't see that you were extending ApplicationClass with Application. The reason why you're getting null is that Applicaton is called before any activity is started. What you can do is, instead of using `ApplicationClass` object, put the value of `getIntent().getExtras().getString("StockName")` in a static string variable and access the static variable in `Table` class.

Comment: result is same but this time there is no exception instead `sname` has returned `null`. Please see my edit in question

Comment: can you please check if you're getting any value in this - `getIntent().getExtras().getString("StockName")`?

Comment: yes @joel I am getting value just printed the value but the value is not getting carried to another class..not sure why... Thanks for your continous assistance

Comment: Thanks @joelFernandes for your assistance finally able to solve the problem... your suggestions are correct but only mistake I was done is invoked the `Table` data object before the value is set to variable... so it was always giving me the `null`...now solved

Answer (score 3):

You should define your subclassed application class in your manifest. And you should never call "new ApplicationClass()". You can get a reference to ApplicationClass instance using activity's getApplication() method.

Detail.java:

```
public class Detail extends Activity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stockdetail);
    ApplicationClass app = (ApplicationClass)getApplication();
    app.setStockName("blah");
}
}
```

Table.java

```
public class Table {
public String selectDate;
public Table(Activity a)
{
    ApplicationClass ac=(ApplicationClass)a.getApplication();
    selectdate="Select " + column1 + " as _id, " + column2 + " From " + tablename + " Where " + column3 + " = " 
                            + ac.getStockName();
}
```

Instantiate Table.java

```
public NewActivity extends Activity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Table t = new Table(this);

}
}
```

Comment: This means can I use `getApplication().getStockname`?

Comment: I am not getting any `getApplication()` in the target class

Comment: You need to pass the activity reference in the target class. <activity>.getApplication() should work.

Comment: I am bit confused here... target class where I am using this variable is not activity its just a class.. `Table` class in my question. In this case how to use the variable in application class

Comment: In your table class, add a setActivity method and store a reference to your activity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Step 1: Create a static Bundle object in Application class.( ApplicationClass.java)

E.g :

```
     public static Bundle mMyAppsBundle = new Bundle():
```

Step 2:

Set key values pair in that bundle from anywhere.
like this:

```
   ApplicationClass.mMyAppsBundle.putString("key","value");
```

Step 3:

Now you can get these values from anywhere  like this way:

```
   String str = ApplicationClass.mMyAppsBundle.getString("key");
```

Please apply null check before using bundle objects for safety points of view.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Lavekush but where and how to set the value for the key? can you please elaborate a bit on this

Comment: There is no `SetString`.. do you mean `put`?

Comment: I have tried `putString` but still the result is same value is null in `Value`

Comment: Remember You just need to create bundle object in ApplicationClass only one.

Comment: setting values code: `ApplicationClass.mMyAppsBundle.putString("SName", stockname);` this is  in one class where I am setting value.. now retriving the value in another class like this `ApplicationClass.mMyAppsBundle.getString("SName")`

Comment: please also paste your application class.

Comment: here is my application class:  `public class ApplicationClass extends Application{
 
 
 public static Bundle mMyAppsBundle = new Bundle();
  
  
 

}`

Comment: Please add oncreate() in Application class. And then try.

Comment: When I added like this it giving me error `Only final is accepted`....`public void onCreate() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate();
  public static Bundle mMyAppsBundle = new Bundle();
 }`

Comment: Application class also having onCreate() method.

Comment: please see my post.. I have implmented `oncreate`

Comment: public static Bundle mMyAppsBundle; then in oncreate mMyAppsBundle = new Bundle(): try this now

Comment: Please paste your application class again

Comment: `public class ApplicationClass extends Application{
 
 public static Bundle mMyAppsBundle;
 
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate();
  mMyAppsBundle = new Bundle();
 }
 
 
  
  
 

}`

Comment: Now can you tell me where you involve put and get methods?

Comment: actually I was able to solve the issue but I would like to try with your approach as well....setting the values in Activity class as `ApplicationClass.mMyAppsBundle.putString("SName", stockname);` and retriving the value in another class as `ApplicationClass.mMyAppsBundle.getString("SName")` both are different classes.. when I implemented this.. I was getting `Null pointer exception`. Thanks for your continous assistance

Comment: If thus is resolving your issue please accept my answer.

Comment: No your answer is still giving me the error.. I have tried different approach and its worked but still intrested in trying your approach as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize firstly your class. But what I see you want to have some application context that is accessible via application. For that porpouse you can simply use that method but data try to keep in `SharedPreferences`. So simply when you get sth from `ApplicationClass` you simply get it firstly from shared preferences and return. :) And each time when you need your ApplicationClass you initialize it and there methods run shared preferences to get data.

```
public class Detail extends Activity{

ApplicationClass ac = new ApplicationClass();

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stockdetail);
        ac=new ApplicationClass();

        ac.setStockName(getIntent().getExtras().getString("StockName"));
}
```

Shared preferences context class.

```
public ApplicationClassWithSharedPreferences{
   private Context context;
   public ApplicationClassWithSharedPreferences(Context c){
       context = c;
   }

   public String getSomeValueFromContext(){
      SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      String highScore = sharedPref.getString("KEY", "DEFAULT");
      return highScore;

   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. how can I use shared preference... some insight on that...

Comment: Check my answer again ;) There is sample you can get more about SharedPreferences in http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Ok can this be written in `Application class`

Comment: @Rafik991.. still banging my head with the issue... can you please where can I declare `SharePreferences` also how and where can I set and get values.

Comment: Read my answer again, I provided there sample `get` method.