# onActivityResult to pick image with putExtra()

Tags: java, android

Want to set the value `RESULT` from the following part and should retrieve it in the `onActivityResult`...

Following is the code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                System.out.println("Select Display Picture, but");
                intent.putExtra("RESULT", "RESULT");
                activity.startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Display Picture"),
                        Credentials.BROWSE_PIC);
                activity.setResult(Credentials.BROWSE_PIC, intent);


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == Credentials.BROWSE_PIC
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
//returning null always here..
            System.out.println("OnActivityResult came in::: "
                    + data.getStringExtra("RESULT"));
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

        }
```

Comment: Are you calling `finish()` once you set the result?

Comment: no, if i do so the activity is finished off//

Comment: If you don't call `finish()`, your `onActivityResult()` won't be fired. If you want to send `Intent`s between `Activity`s without closing them, you probably want to use a local `BroadcastReceiver` instead.

Comment: i am getting the image and everything else... only the data.getStringExtra("RESULT") is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **implicit Intent**, you can not put anything in this intent because every implicit intent is defined by others.

If you want to add something then you can use your own **Global Bundle object** for the same.

Here are important link for you:

You can see answer By Lavekush Agrawer for using Global Bundle Object. here [access the variable in activity in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759644/access-the-variable-in-activity-in-another-class/22760500#22760500)

[Android Intents - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Comment: are u sure that both are not possible with the same intent?

Comment: Yes sure you can not put extra KEY/VALUE pair which is not defined by implicit intent. Think about that if you putting something in intent then it will send to That activity(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT) in Gallery Activity , Your value are found in there not in onActivityResult(),