# Use variable declared in different Java class in android

Tags: java, android

I am working with android studio.

I have a variable declared in MainActivity.java file and would like to use the same variable in another class,say, Records.java file.

In MainActivity.java:

```
public void parse(String response)
{

           //some code
     String token = //some code //use code in Records class

     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Records.class);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

In RecordsActivity.java:

```
public class Records extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //use token variable here
}
```

So, as per the above code I want to use the token variable declared in MainActivity and use it in Records.java
Is this even allowed to do so?

Comment: If you want to use value  store in token ,then use bundle to pass data from 1 activity to another.

Or else declare this variable as static.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759644/access-the-variable-in-activity-in-another-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the following way:

```java
String token = //some code //use code in Records class
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Records.class);
intent.putExtra("token" , token )
startActivity(intent);
```

to get the intent use in onCreate():

```java
Intent intent = getIntent();
String sToken= intent.getStringExtra("token");
```